# JVM GC demote object to eden space?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm guessing this isn't possible...but here goes. My understanding is that eden space is cheaper to collect than old gen space, especially when you start getting into very large heaps. Large heaps tend to come up with long running applications (server apps) and server apps a lot of the time want to use some kind of caches. Caches with some kind of eviction (LRU) tend to defeat some assumptions that GC makes (temporary objects die quickly). So cache evictions end up filling up old gen faster than you'd like and you end up with a more costly old gen collection.

Now, it seems like this sort of thing could be avoided if java provided a way to mark a reference as about to die (delete keyword)? The difference between this and c++ is that the use is optional. And calling delete does not actually delete the object, but rather is a hint to the GC that it should demote the object back to Eden space (where it will be more easily collected). I'm guessing this feature doesn't exist, but, why not (is there a reason it's a bad idea)?

Comment: +1 because I like GC questions. They're hard.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the eden space is the zone of memory in which objects are newly created. Once an object leaves the eden space it cannot be placed there again, then the GC implementation of Java is so much opaque that there is usually not much to do.

It would break some constrains in any case, the eden space is easily garbage collected in the sense that keep care of removing items that have a short life span. If an object survived enough time then it has to be moved somewhere else, it would be like trying to go against the rules imposed by the GC itself, which is something that is never easily obtainable in Java..

Comment: not sure i agree but call it something else then. make a purgatory space dedicated to object references that are probably dead. by moving the object reference out of old gen you're reducing old gen size and creating a relatively small space that can easily be collected. In a case where old gen is say 20GB or whatever, avoiding  full GC is worth a little trouble!